# jQuery select class with a number. e.g. foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select a list of divs (foo#) and fadeIn another div (zxcv#) on hover. I assigned a var in javascript but the end effect is only showing in foo6?

```
<div class="foo1"><div class="zxcv1"></div></div>
<div class="foo2"><div class="zxcv2"></div></div>
<div class="foo3"><div class="zxcv3"></div></div>
<div class="foo4"><div class="zxcv4"></div></div>
<div class="foo5"><div class="zxcv5"></div></div>
<div class="foo6"><div class="zxcv6"></div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        $(".foo"+i).hover(
                function ()
                {
                    $(".zxcv"+i).fadeIn();
                }, function ()
                {
                    $(".zxcv"+i).fadeOut();
                });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that #6 would be affected at all: for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {  It says less than 6, meaning 1-5 only.

Comment: @ChrisGessler: After the loop ends `i` is going to be 6, and that's the (only) value that the callbacks will see.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an "[attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector:

```
$("div[class^='foo']").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("div[class^='zxcv']").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find("div[class^='zxcv']").fadeOut();
});
```

That removes the need for a loop, since most jQuery methods apply to every element in the set.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing over the loop variable `i` in your callbacks, which has the end result that `i` is always `6` inside them (you can check this out with `console.log` or `alert`).

To solve the problem you need to make sure that each of your callbacks gets its own value of `i`. Since Javascript variables are not scoped to blocks but to whole functions, this means that you need to call a function with the current value of `i` each time:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $(".foo"+i).hover(
                function ()
                {
                    $(".zxcv"+i).fadeIn();
                }, function ()
                {
                    $(".zxcv"+i).fadeOut();
                });
    })(i);
}
```

A couple of notes:

- The loop condition is `i < 6` instead of `i <= 6` -- is this a bug?
- As others have already said, in this specific case you can avoid the closure problem entirely by using a different selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all with `$("[class^='foo']")` (also see [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)):

```
$("[class^='foo']").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find("[class^='zxcv']").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find("[class^='zxcv']").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Also see [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/HgCvt/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Try use :nth-child()

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    $(".foo:nth-child("+i+")").hover(
            function ()
            {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            }, function ()
            {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            });
    }
```