# Select a class that starts with e and end with numerical value. ex- e1, e2, e3

Tags: jquery

I want to select those classes in jquery that starts with e and end with a numerical value.

i am using

```
$('[class^="e"]').hide();
```

but it selects even those classes that do not end with a numerical value.

Comment: You can do it using regex selectors. Please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: what if there is another class also for that element... anyway this will be a very inefficient operation... why can't you add another class to all those elements like `e-num` along with `e-<digit>` like `div class="e-num e-6"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery select class with a number. e.g. foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259213/jquery-select-class-with-a-number-e-g-foo1-foo2-foo3-foo4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("div:regex(class, ^e[0-9]+$)").hide()
```

This uses the `:regex` selector by James Padolsey. Get the [regex selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) here.